# Wordpress user search query order by most recent login

Tags: wordpress

I'm creating a custom user search results page and would like to order the results by a) post_count (easily done) but also b) by when the user last logged in - i.e. most recently active users.

Is this even possible? Is there a user meta field in the db for login date?

This is what I have so far:

```
$args = array(
                'number' => $users_per_page,
                'paged' => $current_page
                );
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please include a summary of what you have tried so far and the relevant code in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), as described in [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users). As it is, your question is off-topic.

Comment: @FluffyKitten I have updated the question to show the code I had. Thanks for being pedantic instead of just answering the question.

Comment: That wasn't pedantry, they are the *actual terms* for using this site. You are expected to have at least attempted to solve your problem yourself, as described in the articles linked to. The reason being: without enough information, it isn't possible for me or anyone else to actually answer your question. Technically your question could have been flagged for deletion for not adhering to the terms of the site; instead I explained how you could improve it to avoid that.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the answer to this. I found the meta key `last_activity`.

```
$args = array(
            'order'          => 'DESC',
            'orderby'        => 'last_activity',
            'number' => $users_per_page,
            'paged' => $current_page
            );
```